# How to search for related data using Plastic/Elasticsearch?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, indexing, eloquent, relationship

I'm using Laravel 5, [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) 5 and [Plastic](https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic) in a e-commerce(like) project. Through the use of Elasticsearch and Plastic I'm able to create indexed data, allied to a powerful searching tool, while still working with Eloquent models. In this way, I'm expecting to be able to make what we could consider as extremely heavy querys (with lots of JOIN and LIKE), simple and fast. *Expecting 63 million queries a day...*

Said that, I'm having an issue with the following situation:

> I have a table Department and a table Employee, they are related. I'm
>   searching for Departments and using a keyword that may only exist in
>   some column from Employee's table, is it possible to get all
>   Departments where there are Employees with that keyword?

Example:
When searching Departments with keyword 'Xbox', the system should be able to provide all departments with Employees that mention 'Xbox' in their profile.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting around, the solution was found. You must:

1. Relate the models in Laravel (check Eloquent Relationships at Laravel Documentation)
2. Make the appropriate mapping in the model, using the [buildDocument()](https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic#2---providing-a-builddocument-method) function
3. Make it searchable ([as per example](https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic#1---providing-a-searchable-property-to-our-model))
4. Rebuild your mappings
5. Regenerate your indexes

And that's it.